# Replace array dynamically

Tags: php, arrays

I have this situation

```
$array = ['apples', 'tomatoes'];

$items = ['bananas'];
```

I want to replace apples with bananas but to remove tomatoes if in items I don't have any other value.

When I tried to use `array_replace` I got this

```
dd(array_replace($array, $items));

array = [
  0: "bananas",
  1: "tomatoes"
]
```

How to check if array items has more than one key and replace to corresponding ones?

Comment: is the decision to replace based only on its position in the array?, ie. you replace $array[0] with $items[0]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key), which takes the values of the first argument, and only keeps those where the key exists in both arrays:

```
array_intersect_key($items, $array);
// array( 0 => 'bananas' );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem by using PHP array_replace function here this code will always change 1 index value if you want to change 0 array index value then no need to use array index.

`$orgArray`  is my main array and I am changing  `$orgArray`  `array [1]` index value with `$replacementValue` array value .

```
$orgArray = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");
$replacementValue = array(1 => "grape");

$newArray = array_replace($orgArray, $replacementValue);
print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to his question: "[...] but to remove tomatoes if in items I don't have any other value" - your code won't